# android kotlin mlkit transtation library version error

Tags: android, kotlin, google-mlkit

I am using MLKit to transalte text but whenever i run there is no direct error but the log shows the following and the translated text is always null

`W/LibraryVersion: Failed to get app version for libraryName: shared-installation-id D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler: Scheduling upload for context TransportContext(cct, VERY_LOW, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MGNjL2xvZy9iYXRjaD9mb3JtYXQ9anNvbl9wcm90bzNc) with jobId=-653056373 in 86400000ms(Backend next call timestamp 0). Attempt 1 W/LibraryVersion: Failed to get app version for libraryName: shared-remote-config D/MLKit RemoteConfigRestC: Got remote config. I/TetheringManager: registerTetheringEventCallback:com.example.agrithonapp D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore: Storing event with priority=VERY_LOW, name=FIREBASE_ML_SDK for destination cct D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler: Upload for context TransportContext(cct, VERY_LOW, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MGNjL2xvZy9iYXRjaD9mb3JtYXQ9anNvbl9wcm90bzNc) is already scheduled. Returning... D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore: Storing event with priority=VERY_LOW, name=FIREBASE_ML_SDK for destination cct D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler: Upload for context TransportContext(cct, VERY_LOW, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MGNjL2xvZy9iYXRjaD9mb3JtYXQ9anNvbl9wcm90bzNc) is already scheduled. Returning... D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore: Storing event with priority=VERY_LOW, name=FIREBASE_ML_SDK for destination cct D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler: Upload for context TransportContext(cct, VERY_LOW, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MGNjL2xvZy9iYXRjaD9mb3JtYXQ9anNvbl9wcm90bzNc) is already scheduled. Returning... D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore: Storing event with priority=VERY_LOW, name=FIREBASE_ML_SDK for destination cct D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler: Upload for context TransportContext(cct, VERY_LOW, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MGNjL2xvZy9iYXRjaD9mb3JtYXQ9anNvbl9wcm90bzNc) is already scheduled. Returning...`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Have you tried if the ML Kit translate demo works on your device?
https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/translate